# Reference enum values in Angular template without aliasing the enum type

Tags: template, typescript, enum, angular-2+

Is there a way to improve this code? I'd like to use the enum type `PaymentMethod`directly in the angular template without renaming it to `_PaymentMethod`.

---

```
export enum PaymentMethod {
    CreditCard,
    EFT
}

@Component()
export class PaymentComponent {
    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    _PaymentMethod = PaymentMethod;

    paymentMethod: PaymentMethod;
}

<ng-template *ngIf="paymentMethod == _PaymentMethod.CreditCard">
   Enter your card details
</ng-template>
```